Where can I find a power supply that plugs into the wall to get 120VAC and outputs 120VAC at a controlled wattage(5-60w)?
I need to supply a constant set wattage (30 watts) at 120VAC to my in-line air heater (it has 2 leads). What would be the best way to go about this?

P=U^2/R.
These are the parameters you have to play with.

what is wrong with using a thermal switch?

your post appears to be an XY question... asking for help with a perceived solution to an unspecified problem, instead of asking for help with the problem

Controlling wattage specifically is probably the most difficult way to control a heater and I doubt it's actually the way to accomplish what you want to do. Are you trying to maintain a set temperature?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is clear that the rated voltage of the heater is 120 V. What is it's rated wattage?

The way most power supplies that I am familiar with work is that they set a voltage (whether 120V AC in and out, which can actually be a thing for safety reasons to not just wire directly through; or 120V AC in and some AC voltage higher (240V) or lower (20V, 12V, etc.) out; or 120V AC in and some voltage (typically low - anywhere from 3V to 48V) out) and, depending on how well-designed, maintain that voltage through a wide range of output current.
However, the current, and by extension the total power, depends on what the device using the power "needs". A simple example is a light socket connected to a 120V AC supply. With incandescent bulbs:

If your bulb has a 360 Ohm resistance filament then it will draw 0.33A of current and produce 40W of light/heat.
If your bulb has a 240 Ohm resistance filament then it will draw 0.5A of current and produce 60W of light/heat.
If your bulb has a 192 Ohm resistance filament then it will draw 0.625A of current and produce 75W of light/heat.
If your bulb has a 144 Ohm resistance filament then it will draw 0.83A of current and produce 100W of light/heat.

With more complex loads (e.g., computers) it is not such a simple calculation, but the result is the same: The power supply (whether a generator or a battery backup or an entire utility grid) will supply as little or as much power as the load actually needs.
The end result is that you either:

Fine-tune the load (e.g., adjust the resistance of a wire by changing the material or making it longer or shorter) to require, and therefore get and use, the desired amount of power for the desired amount of heat.
Use a larger load than necessary and cycle the load using a thermostat (so it adjusts automatically based on ambient temperature) or a timer (based on typical conditions).


Any incandescent dimmer can vary the wattage of your heater. If you are trying to maintain a fixed temperature, you're going to need temperature process controller.
